# BASH: The variable shows only the last line

Tags: linux, bash

The variable shows only the last line:

```
while read var1; do
    var2+="$var1"$"\n"
    if [[ $var2 == *andoi* ]]; then
        break
    fi
done < "./filename" #or other file
echo "Result:"
echo "$var2" #just read the last lines, I want all
#...edit $var2...etc...
echo "$var2" #modified
```

Simplified script:

```
while read var1; do
    var2+="$var1"$"\n"
done < "./filename" #or other file
echo "$var2" #just read the last lines, I want all
#...edit $var2...cdn...
echo "$var2" #modified
```

I used this http://gsteph.blogspot.com/2007/04/bash-reading-text-file.html

How do teeth variable shows all the lines in one variable?

//I corrected, it may be useful to someone.//

Comment: you just reassign var2 every iteration, you need to combine them

Comment: With recent bash, you can write `var2+="$var1"` but it won't preserve newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to accumulate `$var1` into `$var2`?

```
while read var1; do
  var2="$var2 $var1"
  # etc...
done < "./filename"

echo "$var2"
```

To accumulate them with a newline on each, do:

```
while read var1; do
  var2="$var2
$var1"
  # etc...
done < "./filename"

echo "$var2"
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Can accumulate var1 into var1?
Why did not enter (\n)?

<blockqoute>#!/bin/bash while read var1; do var2="$var2 $var1" ./script.sh echo "$var2"</blockquote>

Comment: Instead of the line break in the second version, I just split string across two lines, closing the `"` on the second line after `$var1"`  Has the same effect as inserting a line break

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the contents of a file up to and including some keyword:

```
x=$(sed '/droid/ q')
x=$(awk '{print} /droid/ {exit}')
```